# Regular Expression in JavaScript - Not Filtering Properly

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression that I am attempting to use to control user input to only allow letters A-D(case insensitive) followed by a numerical value between 1-16.

Ex// A12, C5 are valid entries, but B18 would be invalid as would H2.

The regular expression I am using flags incorrect input based on the alphabetical value, but not the numerical - so in my previous example it is correctly flagging H2, but is allowing B18 to be entered.

I am fairly new to regex and so I am unsure where I've gone astray. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My current expression is as follows:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/([A-Da-d]{1}[1-9]{1}|[A-Da-d]{1}[1]{1}[0-6]{1})/);
```

Thanks again!

Comment: As an aside, there is no need to call the `RegExp()` function if the thing you're passing it is a regex literal. Just say `var regex = /([A-etc./;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex like this with insensitive flag:

```
^[a-d](?:1[0-6]|[0-9])$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/LsTzou/1)**

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please also tell me where I went wrong with my original regex pattern? Just trying to learn so I can improve my ability to figure it out on my own.

Comment: @gothamprince, your first part of the pattern were matching from 1 to 9 without allowing the 2nd part of the match. In your case, the order of your group matters. In addition, you were using lots of `{1}` which are unneeded. You can check your regex diagram here [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/D8OBAukztSIYLFOq), as you can see the first group always matched without allowing the 2nd  part. Also, if you had used anchors it would have worked

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This expression will do it:

```
/^[A-D]([1-9]|1[0-6])$/i
```

```js
var re = /^[A-D]([1-9]|1[0-6])$/i;

console.log(re.test('A12'));
console.log(re.test('C5'));
console.log(re.test('H12'));
console.log(re.test('B18'));
```

Comment: @AndrewShepherd There's an `i` flag at the end of my regex.